# Eliminating only Certain Dates from Java Using Switch Statements

Tags: java, date

I have almost completed my code; however, instead of eliminating solely the dates which fall on Friday and also happen to be the 13th day of the month, it has eliminated every 13th submission.  I thought that:

```
int friday = ((startingDayOfWeek+dayOfYear) % 7);
            if (dayOfYear != 13 && friday != 5)
            System.out.println(month + "/" + dayOfYear);
            dayOfYear++;
```

Would work, but it is eliminating them all.  I understand that there are easier ways to accomplish this; however, I am required to do it in this manner.  Here is the full code:

```
public class LoopDate {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Denotes that Tuesday is the first day of 2013
    int startingDayOfWeek = 2;
    int year = 2013;
    int numDays = 0;
    for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
        switch (month) {
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 10:
        case 12:
            numDays = 31;
            break;
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            numDays = 30;
            break;
        case 2:
            if (((year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100 == 0))
                    || (year % 400 == 0))
                numDays = 29;
            else
                numDays = 28;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid month.");
            break;
        }
        int dayOfYear = 1;
        while (dayOfYear <= numDays)
        {
            int friday = ((startingDayOfWeek+dayOfYear) % 7);
            if (dayOfYear != 13 && friday != 5)
            System.out.println(month + "/" + dayOfYear);
            dayOfYear++;
        }



    }
}
}
```

Comment: In the previous questions people have given me code that I am unable to use in this case.  It was intended to be long winded and not a simple route, so I haven't really received much advice on the matter as pertains to what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I thought it was obvious, why would I come with a block of code just to have the whole thing re-written in 4 lines?

Comment: I ended up fixing it on my own by setting break points and stepping through.  I thought I could have gotten the answer easier here.  Maybe another time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your boolean logic is wrong.

```
if (dayOfYear != 13 && friday != 5)
```

Should be:

```
if (dayOfYear != 13 || friday != 5)
```

You are doing the negative check of "is it friday the 13th". When converting a positive check into a negative check, you need to NOT the conditions (done), and flip the operators (OR becomes AND, AND becomes OR).

Also, when dealing with boolean logic like that, I usually give the segments meaningful names. It 'costs' a variable, but can save you countless hours later on!

```
boolean isFridayThe13th = (dayOfYear == 13 && friday == 5);
if (!isFridayThe13th) ...
```